# Dynamic allocation/ Pointer to Pointer to update an Array containing parameter

Tags: programming, array, pointer

`topicArray` defined as follows:

```
const char* msgTopic = "Home/Messages";
const char* groupTopic = "Home/All";
char* deviceName = deviceTopic;
const char* topicArry[2] = {deviceTopic, groupTopic};
```

But `deviceTopic` can be changed during code run, and I wish that `topicArray` containg `deviceTopic` will have the correct value after `deviceTopic` has changed.

What is the right way doing so ?

Comment: don't make the array 'constant' with `const` and you can change the values (pointers) it contains

Comment: @Juraj I did remove `const` ouf of array and all other variable, but still array is not changed

Comment: do you change it?

Comment: as said " I did remove `const`"

Comment: to be able to set the value `topicArray[0] = "something"`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may try something like this:

```
const char* topicArry[2] = {NULL, groupTopic};
const char** const pDeviceTopic = &topicArry[0];
#define deviceTopic (*pDeviceTopic)
```

Arguably not very elegant, but now when you assign, e.g.

```
deviceTopic = msgTopic;
```

you are actually writing into `topicArry[0]`.